# In the Shopify API, is it possible to retrieve the ordering of products in a collection?

Tags: shopify

We've got a site fetching the products on our Shopify store's frontpage collection, but the Shopify API always returns them alphabetically so we lose the ordering. Is there any way to retrieve the *ordering* of a collection as well as its products?

(I realise I can reorder these products alphabetically via the Shopify interface and then they'd match up with the results of the API call, but we'd like the site that's fetching the details to reflect whatever the current Shopify store ordering is, if that's possible.) Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a Collect.  It has a properties called "position" and "sort_value" that keep track of the manually sorted order in a collection.

[Have a look at this.](https://docs.shopify.com/api/collect)

Comment: Thanks thingEvery, I should have looked more closely - my mistake was in thinking the Featured products weren't a Custom Collection. A similar answer came on the Shopify forums [here](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/in-the-shopify-api-is-it-possible-to-retrieve-the-ordering-of-products-in-a-collection-300313).